# compile code at run-time and use assemblies loaded on memory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, csharpcodeprovider

I need to compile C# code at run-time. I'm using the code like this:

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MyLibrary.dll");    // File Path on Hard Drive
...
```

But I want to use the libraries loaded on memory instead of their file addresses. Is it possible?

Comment: This is a very persistent myth.  "Loaded on memory" is an illusion, current compilers (csc.exe in your case) run out-of-process and read/write assemblies on disk.  All that the GenerateInMemory property does is forcing a call to Assembly.LoadFrom().  So just don't bother.

Answer (score 3):

If it is an assembly that isn't generated in-memory only, you could use:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add
( typeof(ClassInAssemblyYouWantToAdd).Assembly.Location
);
```

Or:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add
( Assembly.Load("Full.Qualified.Assembly.Name").Location
);
```

The [`Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location(v=vs.110).aspx) property has the path to the assembly loaded.

It has to have a hard copy of the assembly, and not just something in memory, so you can't just use generated assemblies for that. You could save the in-memory generated assemblies to disk first if you need to use them.

Comment: I do some pre-process on my assemblies and load them on memory. I have their `Assembly` object. In this case can I use your code?

Comment: Sure. Give it a try and tell me if you experience any problems.

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh: Any luck?

Comment: I try the CodeBase and it returns the file name of the assembly that loads my assemblies on memory.

Comment: If that wrong? You can't just put there in-memory assemblies as explained in the post.

Comment: oh yes, I didn't see that, Is there any way to use the assembly loaded on memory and has no hard copy?

Comment: No, but you can save it first. Set the `compilerParams.OutputAssembly` to a file path.

Comment: Btw, I would suggest `Location` instead of `CodeBase`. It has the full path.

Comment: I really appreciate you because of your answers.

Comment: I've encrypted my assemblies and I want to decrypt them before loading or using. In this case I should save my decrypted assemblies in hard drive and this isn't good.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but worth a test: try handling [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx). Check if it catches the referenced assembly (then you don't need the path, just the FQN).

Comment: Too bad. Also see Hans' comment. I think there is not much to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not find a solution yet. Really thank you Patrick for your attention. If I find a solution I will certainly inform you :)

Comment: I used Roslyn to extract the public interface of my assemblies. Now I'm using these generated assemblies for compilation. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699799/compile-c-sharp-code-dynamically-without-using-original-required-assemblies)